# Html not loading

Tags: css, html

Im quite new to html and i bet i'm missing something but im creating a simple html and css to go along with it. i get 404 whenever i preview my work.

this is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>   
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Basic Structure</title>


    <!-- !CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fbtab/fbtab.css">

   </head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <header>
            <div id="logo"><img src="/fbtab/images/logo.png"/></div>
        </header><!-- end header -->

        </div><!-- end container -->

    <!-- !Javascript - at the bottom for fast page loading -->

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the css:

```
html,
container,
header, 
body {
 width:800px;
 height:100%;
 min-height:100%;
}
```

Can someone guide me to the proper way of creating new html page?
i just need a 800px width page and want to put logo and icons for it and a background.

Thank you.

Comment: A 404 error means that your browser cannot find the file at the specified address. Where are you hosting the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That does not have to do anything with your HTML. A 404 error means that a page does not exist. Maybe the file upload (of your HTML) has failed. Your server cannot find the file you have requested. Check via FTP if your files have been properly uploaded.

Comment: well..the files are in the right place but it seems i have a storage issue because i switched servers during the night so yeah it must be outside issue...but regardless..i only get a blue question mark when i test locally..is the logo path correct for local? img src="/images/logo.png"/></div> that file is inside images folder

Answer (score 1):

A 404 error is an HTTP status code that means that the page you were trying to reach on a website couldn't be found on their server. (and has no relation with page layout and design)

Technically, an Error 404 is a client-side error, implying that the error is your mistake, either because you typed the URL in wrong or the page has been moved or removed from the website and you should have known.

But in your case, if you are calling the domain (like google.com) and not a specific page (like google.com/index.html);

- Make sure that you have given the name **index.html** to your web page
- Make sure that you have uploaded / created / copied your index.html file in the server root directory (**htdocs** folder).

Answer (score -1):

Try to add `<html>` tag before `<head>`.